# Save a char* parameter intro a string

Tags: c++, c++14, googletest, googlemock

Please help me with this question.. I'm beginner with gtest.
I have a mocked function

```
DoSomething(const char* par0, const char* par2)
```

I want to save its second argument into

```
    std::string `savedPar_`;

EXPECT_CALL(mockd_, DoSomething(_, _,))
        .WillOnce(DoAll(SaveArg<1>(savedPar_), (Return(Ok))));
```

And got this error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’)
   *pointer = ::testing::get<k>(args);
```

Than you so much in advance!

Comment: I don't know googletest/gmock very well but why isn't `par2` involved in the assignment?

Comment: @TedLyngmo what do you mean with that ? SaveArg<1> should save par2

Comment: Ok, that just shows how little I know googletest/gmock :-)

Comment: What is `pointer`? Looks like it's actually a string from the error message. As the error says, `std::string` does not have a `operator *`

Comment: @ChrisMM can you please tell me how it would work ?

Comment: if I use char* for savedPar_ I got other erros.

Comment: Please show a [mre], otherwise, we are just guessing.

Comment: I think it might be a simple question for somoene who really masters gtest. 
What other thing should I add in such example to fulfill the minimal reproducible example ? Thank you.

Comment: Any idea how can I save one of the arguments from DoSomething() ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/reference/actions.md#side-effects)

> `SaveArg<N>(pointer)` Save the N-th (0-based) argument to `*pointer`.

It should be:

```
std::string savedPar_;

EXPECT_CALL(mockd_, DoSomething(_, _,))
        .WillOnce(DoAll(SaveArg<1>(&savedPar_), (Return(Ok))));
//                                 ^
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed the & from savedPar_. 
One more question please if possible. 
How could I use savedPar_ in other expect_call not only after test is done ?

Comment: Open a new question.

Comment: ok, I need to create a new account for that.